# How do you Edit MP4 ID3 Tags in Java?

Tags: java, mp4, id3

I asked a similar question some time ago, but with python, and have since then decided to switch to Java because there seemed to be more resources to do this sort of thing. Basically I need some sort of library, idea, or instructions that would allow me to edit ID3 tags in an MP4 file like the kind found in iTunes. If anyone knows anything, your help would be greatly appreciated.

So far I've done the following:

1. I've found this question/answer to a very similar problem: [How do you Edit Video ID3v2 Tags in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144864/how-do-you-edit-video-id3v2-tags-in-java) (it describes how to use a library intended for audio files called JID3 to edit video ID3 tags), but I can't figure out for the life of me how to actually import it into an eclipse project and use it. I basically unpacked it and added all the packages into the project, but the one time it worked it made the movie file unreadable to any media player afterwards. If anyone has specific knowledge of how to import and use JID3 that would be great.
2. I've found this site: http://willcode4beer.com/parsing.jsp?set=mp3ID3 which has some seemingly good code for reading and writing ID3 tags, unfortunately it does not work properly constantly returning strings of question marks or telling me that the file is not there spontaneously (it will literally work one time and then not work another time without any changes). Nevertheless I like the idea of simply reading the bytes or ASCII of a file and finding/editing the ID3 tag that way so if anyone knows what to do for that, that'd be awesome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you looked at http://www.id3.org/ ?

Answer (score 1):

The metadata in MP4 is not necessarily in ID3 format. There is the possibility to use ID3 but it is not widely used. The ID3 bytes are then in /moov/meta/id32 box.
The iTunes files bear their meta information in /moov/udta/... there are multiple boxes like '@cmt', '@nam', '@des', '@cpy' that contain each a string for (in this case) comment, name, description, copyright. Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/ to visualize, parse and write MP4 files.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to be able to edit such metadata as: artist, track, cover image etc. and then be able to see your changes in iTunes or QuickTime.

In that case you may want to look at the new API available in JCodec ([org.jcodec.movtool.MetadataEditor](https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jcodec/movtool/MetadataEditor.java)).
 It also has a CLI ([org.jcodec.movtool.MetadataEditorMain](https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jcodec/movtool/MetadataEditorMain.java)).

Here's the basic usage:

```
# Changes the author of the movie
./metaedit -f -si ©ART=New\ value file.mov
```

or the same thing via the Java API:

```
MetadataEditor mediaMeta = MetadataEditor.createFrom(new
    File("file.mp4"));
Map<Integer, MetaValue> meta = mediaMeta.getItunesMeta();
meta.put(0xa9415254, MetaValue.createString("New value")); // fourcc for '©ART'
mediaMeta.save(false); // fast mode is off
```

You can find a complete documentation here: http://jcodec.org/docs/working_with_mp4_metadata.html